# HTTP to HTTPS mod_rewrite with clean URLs

Tags: apache, security, mod-rewrite, https, clean-urls

I am using Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I would like to be able to redirect a URL like this

**mysite.com/privacy**

to

**https://www.mysite.com/privacy**

The new URL would be secure and return privacy.html while keeping a clean URL

I am currently editing /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf and here is what I have so far

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

I have been able to redirect HTTP to HTTPS (including the addition of www) or access privacy.html using a clean URL but I get resource not found when doing both. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use rewrite, see this: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I used Redirect permanent in my port 80 VirtualHost and I added the clean URL rewrite rule in the port 443 VirtualHost.